# Laurent series for $\frac{e^z}{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Calculate the Laurent series of $\displaystyle\frac{e^z}{z^2}$ when $0<|z|<\infty$.

I know how the terms $a_n$ and $b_n$ of the Laurent series are defined in terms of a closed integral, but I don't think it is really useful to apply them in any situation. What should I do here?

Comment: Take the standard power series for $e^z$ and divide by $z^2$.

Comment: I see. How do I know when to expand a function with a Laurent series then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{e^z}{z^2}=\sum_{n=-2}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n+2)!}$$
And yes, it is usually the other way around: most common usage is the *Residue theorem* where you need $a_{-1}$ to find $\oint f(z)dz$. 
(Particularly for this case it immediately yields
$$\oint\frac{e^z}{z^2}dz=2\pi i$$
around $0$ as $a_{-1}=1$ in this case.)